# LoginView works in Account folder, not in root folder of website

Tags: asp.net, authentication, account, loginview

I have been searching the internet for an answer to my problem and have read through the msdn site on ASP.Net controls, security and authentication but either cannot find the answer or missed it with all the information I have read.

I am building a website in ASP.Net v2.0 to be hosted on a remote server. I am using MySQL as the back end which also contains the user tables. I have used the same user table structure as that used in the default membership table. The folders in the application all have the default role privileges assigned to them.

The following problem is occurring in my testing on my local computer.

When I login a user using the `~/Account/Login.aspx` page I redirect the user to `~/Account/AccountDetails.aspx`, which contains a `LoginView`. After logging in, the user name is visible on this page inside the `LoginView` and they are Authenticated.

When I then go to `~/Default.aspx`, and using the same code for the `LoginView`, the username is not displaying and they are no longer Authenticated.

I do not want to create multiple pages to show the same data, as both logged in and anonymous users need to see the same information in the `~/Default.aspx` page. I was just hoping to show that the user is logged in on the `Default.aspx` page or any page in the `~/` folder.

I know it is going to be a simple setting or change that is required, like a role or membership or something, but I cannot figure it out.

I have looked through stackoverflow and found a lot of `LoginView` questions, but cannot seem to find one that answers my question.

I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Here is the code used on both the `Default.aspx` and `AccountDetails.aspx` pages. It is the default `LoginView` code from the template `ASP.Net` website application.

```
<div class="loginDisplay">
  User Authenticated? <%= Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>
  <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
      [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
      Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
      [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
  </asp:LoginView>
</div>
```

The `~/Account/web.config` file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  

  <location path="Register.aspx">  
    <system.web>  
      <authorization>  
        <allow users="*"/>  
      </authorization>  
    </system.web>  
  </location>  


  <system.web>  
    <authorization>  
      <deny users="?" />  
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

The `~/web.config` file contains the following information. I have edited some of the values for username and passwords. I have also removed the commented lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  
  <connectionStrings>  
    <add name="MySqlMembershipConnection" connectionString="Data Source=mydatasource;user id=dotnet;password=dotnet;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />    
    <add name="mycs" connectionString="Dsn=mydsn" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />    
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />    
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="database=mydsn;server=localhost;User Id=dotnet;password=dotnet" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>    
  <system.web>    
    <sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">    
      <providers>    
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" />    
      </providers>    
    </sessionState>    
    <authentication mode="Forms">    
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="30" name=".ASPXFORM$" path="~/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />    
    </authentication>    
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">    
      <providers>    
        <clear />    
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />    
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="mydescription" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="True" requiresUniqueEmail="False" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />    
      </providers>    
    </membership>    
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">    
      <providers>    
        <clear />    
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />    
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" />    
      </providers>    
    </profile>    
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">    
      <providers>    
        <clear />    
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />    
        <add applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True"
      name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />    
      </providers>    
    </roleManager>    
    <customErrors mode="Off" />    
    <compilation debug="true" />    
  </system.web>    

  <system.net>    
    <mailSettings>    
      <smtp from="user@domain.com">    
        <network host="mail.domain.com" password="mypassword" userName="myusername" />    
      </smtp>    
    </mailSettings>    
  </system.net>    

  <system.webServer>    
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />    
  </system.webServer>    

</configuration>
```

Comment: can't you share what is configured in your web.config? what says authorization tag? <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

Comment: Hi, it is the standard web.config settings that come with the template ASP.NET website.

Comment: can you give me an snapshot of web.config in your root folder? does it contains authorization tag?

Comment: also have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx. this shows a very basic form authetication

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I already have the web.config files as listed above in the directories and am using the ASP.Net controls to authorize the users, not C# code. Should I be replacing the controls with the C# code listed on the MSDN page? It is something that I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: you have no authorization tag in ~/web.config.. try placing it in ~/web.config.

Comment: Hi, so I tried adding the location block from `~/Account/web.config` into the `~/web.config` file in between the connectionStrings and system.web blocks and I still get the same results. So then I added the <authorization><allow users="*"/></authorization> inside the actual system.web block after the authentication block and this too did not work. I also changed the * to a ? hoping this might resolve the problem but it too did not work.

Comment: it should work this way.. seems like something else is wrong with deployment..... allow users="?" should work. btw are you using virtual directory? for Account folder? or this is the same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much testing I figured out where the problem was. Firstly, I had three connection strings, one for the data and two for the forms authentication. I combined the two forms authentication connection strings into a single connection string. This allows me to have one connection string for data and one for authentication.

Next, I wanted to find out where my problem was occurring, so I created a new blank `ASP.NET` website in VS 2010 and then step by step, added in support for `MySQL`. This was done by adding in the MySQL Data and Web references first, then the connection strings and then finally the forms authentication.

I noticed in the forms element in the system.web authentication element, that it only included the loginURL and timeout attributes, so I tested the application by adding in additional attributes for the forms element until I found the attribute causing the problem.

In my forms element the path attribute was set to '~/'. When I changed this to '/' the application started to work correctly.